Validity of Python-derived solution for contour integral $\oint f(z)f(z-\overline{z})~dz$
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
$$
\mbox{Consider the function:}\quad
\on{f}\left(z\right) =
\frac{{\rm e}^{tz}}{\left(1 + z^{2}\right)^{3}}\,
\left(\sqrt{t} - t\right)\ \ni\ t,z \in \mathbb{C}
$$
$$
\mbox{Evaluate:}\quad
\oint_{C}\on{f}\left(z\right)\on{f}\left(z-\bar{z}\right)\,{\rm d}z
$$
where $C$ is a contour circle with radius of $10$. ( here $\bar{z}$ defines complex conjugate of $z$ ).
I have been trying to solve this through a
Python Code:
from sympy import *
# Define symbols and function 
z, t = symbols('z t', imaginary=True) 
f = (exp(t*z) / ((1 + z**2)**3))*(sqrt(t)-t) 
g =f.subs(z,z-conjugate(z)) 
h = f * g 
#since h has only higher order poles we find the points of poles and apply expansions 
poles = roots(Eq(f.as_numer_denom()[1],0),z) 
#apply expansion residue formulae  
exper = [] 
for i in poles.items():   
    expansion = series(f,z,i[0],i[1]+1)   
    exper.append(expansion.coeff((z-i[0])**(-1))) 
#apply residue theorem  
ans = 2*pi*I*(sum(exper)) 

and have reached here with sympy and google collab, this code solved the problem as :
$$\boxed{\displaystyle\,\,\,\oint_{C}\on{f}\left(z\right)
\on{f}\left(z-\bar{z}\right)\,{\rm d}z =
\frac{3\pi\left[-\sqrt{t} + t +
\left(\sqrt{t} - t\right){\rm e}^{2{\rm i}t}\right]
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}t}}{8}\,\,\,}
$$
But I doubt this solution is wrong.
Can any of you please check if this answer is correct ??.

It says "a circle of radius $10$".  It does not say which circle of radius $10$??  If it is the circle $|z|=10$, then we can write $\overline{z} = 100/z$ to get an analytic function to use.

@GEdgar You're right. Objection withdrawn.

That said, there's still a complication: if $\bar{z}=100/z$, then under the substitution $z=10e^{i\theta}$ the function $f(z-\overline{z})=f(20i\sin \theta)$ contains the factor $1+(20i\sin \theta)^2=1-400\sin^\theta$ in its denominator. But this vanishes when $\sin\theta=1/20$, so the integrand is singular at these points and thus one has to be careful when using the residue theorem.
